# Get an array with non duplicate values from multiple array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I need to go through multiple arrays and create one new array with all the values from the multiple arrays without duplicate, is there any plugins/quick way I can do this?

```
var x = {
  "12": [3, 4],
  "13": [3],
  "14": [1, 4]
};
```

The result should look something like this:

```
[1,3,4];
```

Comment: Please use the snippet editor to create a [mcve] that shows your effort and code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the difference between two arrays in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: `[...new Set([].concat.apply([], Object.values(x)))]`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using ES6 spread syntax and `Object.values` method.

```js
var x = {
  "12": [3, 4],
  "13": [3],
  "14": [1, 4]
}

const result = [...new Set([].concat(...Object.values(x)))]
console.log(result)
```

Solution using **Lodash**

```js
var x = {
  "12": [3, 4],
  "13": [3],
  "14": [1, 4]
}

const result = _.uniq(_.flatten(_.values(x)))
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have this error: '[ts] Type 'Set<any>' is not an array type.'

Comment: @Adam you did not tag this TypeScript

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#from` with `set` and `array#reduce`.

```js
var x = {"12": [3, 4],"13": [3],"14": [1, 4]};
    result = Array.from(new Set(Object.values(x).reduce((r,a) => r.concat(a), [])));
console.log(result)
```

You can also get all values from your object and create an object and get all the keys from it.

```js
var x = {"12": [3, 4],"13": [3],"14": [1, 4]};
    result = Object.keys(Object
                        .values(x)
                        .reduce((r,a) => (a.forEach(v => r[v] = true), r),{})
                        ).map(Number);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over all your keys and then your arrays:

```
var outputArray = [];
for (var y in x) {
    for (var z = 0; z < x[y].length; z++) {
        if (outputArray.indexOf(x[y][z]) === -1) {
            outputArray.push(x[y][z]);
        }
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/80c8ctuo/

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the arrays using `Object.values` and then merge them into one array using `concat`. Following this you can use `filter` to remove duplicates.

```js
const x = {"12": [3, 4],"13": [3],"14": [1, 4]};
const result = [].concat.apply([], Object.values(x)).filter((el, i, a) => i === a.indexOf(el));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance the object is from `JSON.parse` :

```js
var j = '{ "12": [3, 4], "13": [3], "14": [1, 4] }'

var a = [], x = JSON.parse(j, (k, v) => (a[v] = +v, v))

console.log( a.filter(isFinite) )
```